# Symfony's Unique Entity not working at all

Tags: php, symfony, entity

I've been using Symfony for a while and I've already done validation with Unique Entity in another project and it worked. I'm trying to create a new project and for some reason Unique Entity won't stop me from inserting duplicate fields.

```
$timetable = new Timetable();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add("name", TextType::class, ["label"=>"Nazwa","attr"=>["class"=>"form-control"]])
        ->add(
            "year",
            ChoiceType::class,
            ["label" => "Rok", "choices" => $years, "attr" => ["class" => "form-control"]]
        )
        ->add(
            "month",
            ChoiceType::class,
            ["label" => "Miesiąc", "choices" => $months, "attr" => ["class" => "form-control"]]
        )
        ->add("dodaj",
            SubmitType::class,
            ["attr"=>["class"=>"btn btn-primary btn-block mt-3"]]
            )
        ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() ){
            $month = $form["month"]->getData();
            $year = $form["year"]->getData();
            $name = $form["name"]->getData();

            $date = new \DateTime("$month.01.$year");
            $timetable->setDate($date);
            $timetable->setName($name);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($timetable);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect("/newtimetable");
        }
```

And this is my entity class:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TimetableRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("date",message="The date is not unique")
 *
 */

class Timetable
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, name="name")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", unique=true, name="date")
     */
    private $date;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate(\DateTimeInterface $date): self
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to create a Timetable object with a unique date field. I do not get any errors, the form just works and creates a new entry.
I tried the same thing with other fields and validation doesn't work anyway.
Could anybody give me some tips on how to get that to work?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you supposed to pass your entity object as the argument to createFormBuilder - do you get the same results with  `$form = $this->createFormBuilder($timetable);`?

Comment: Then I won't be able to create a form with "year" and "month" select fields as they're not actual Entity fields. That is why I didn't pass $timetable as an argument to the formBuilder.

Comment: You were right and the problem is with the parameter. How can I validate the fields that do not belong to the entity but eventually end up as a single entity field?

Comment: Try using the `DateType` form field ([docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html)). Symfony can handle the month/year select boxes for you.

Comment: Just as a troubleshooting measure, ensure that your schema is generated with the correct SQL.  Can you try  bin/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql and paste the result ?

Answer (score 0):

Might be too late for this answer but we never know...

In the annotation of the UniqueEntity, you are missing the parameter fields. So it should work like this :

```
* @UniqueEntity(fields="date", message="The date is not unique")
```